# when I seek to a timestamp using OffsetsForTimes method it give me a timout exeception

Tags: apache-kafka

0

I created a class called ConsumerConfig and Service class that contain fonction that gets records from a topic.

locally it works just fine but when i add the brokers it stopped working and i get timout exception, and it takes a loong time can anybody help me .

here is the code of the ConsumerConfig class and the fonctions that gets records from specific topic :

```
@Component
public class ConsumerConfig {
    private static Integer numberOfConsumer = 0;
    private  KafkaConsumer consumer;

    private Map<String, Object> buildDefaultConfig() {
        final Map<String, Object> defaultClientConfig = new HashMap<>();
        defaultClientConfig.put("bootstrap.servers", (String) getbrokersConfigurationFromFile().get("spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers"));
        defaultClientConfig.put("client.id", "test-consumer-id" + (++numberOfConsumer));
        defaultClientConfig.put("request.timeout.ms",60000);

        return defaultClientConfig;
    }

     @Bean
     @RequestScope
    public <K, V> KafkaConsumer<K, V> getKafkaConsumer() {
        // Build config
        final Map<String, Object> kafkaConsumerConfig = buildDefaultConfig();
        kafkaConsumerConfig.put("key.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
        kafkaConsumerConfig.put("value.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
        kafkaConsumerConfig.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");
         kafkaConsumerConfig.put("max.poll.records",5);
         kafkaConsumerConfig.put("default.api.timeout.ms", 6000000);
         kafkaConsumerConfig.put("max.block.ms ",60000000);
         kafkaConsumerConfig.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");
         kafkaConsumerConfig.put("enable.partition.eof", "false");
         kafkaConsumerConfig.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
         kafkaConsumerConfig.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
         kafkaConsumerConfig.put("session.timeout.ms", "30000");

         //fetch.max.byte The maximum amount of data the server should return for a fetch request.
        // Create and return Consumer.
        return consumer=new KafkaConsumer<K, V> (kafkaConsumerConfig);
    }


}

/**
     * reacd from specific offset timestamp
     */

    public <K, V> List<Record> consumeFromTime(String topicName, Long timestampMs) {
        // Get the list of partitions
        List<PartitionInfo> partitionInfos = consumer.partitionsFor(topicName);
        // Transform PartitionInfo into TopicPartition
        List<TopicPartition> topicPartitionList = partitionInfos
                .stream()
                .map(info -> new TopicPartition(topicName, info.partition()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        // Assign the consumer to these partitions
        consumer.assign(topicPartitionList);
        // Look for offsets based on timestamp


        Map<TopicPartition, Long> partitionTimestampMap = topicPartitionList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(tp -> tp, tp -> System.currentTimeMillis() - timestampMs * 1000));
        Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndTimestamp> partitionOffsetMap = consumer.offsetsForTimes(partitionTimestampMap);
        // Force the consumer to seek for those offsets
        List<ConsumerRecord<K, V>> allRecords = new ArrayList<>();
        partitionOffsetMap.forEach((tp, offsetAndTimestamp) -> {

                    if (!Objects.isNull(offsetAndTimestamp)) {
                        consumer.seek(tp, offsetAndTimestamp.offset());
                        ConsumerRecords<K, V> records;
                        records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100L));
                        records.forEach(allRecords::add);
                    }


                }
        );


        return allRecords.stream().map(v -> Record.builder().values(v.value()).offset(v.offset()).partition(v.partition()).build()).collect(Collectors.toList());

    }
```